# How to read the file content and parse the CSV file from BLOB in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

[image]

I have stored the csv file in blob container and try to read the content from logic app in azure. But i am facing issue to get the contect and iterate the same. Please help with flow.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [edit] a [mcve] into your question instead of posting an image.

Comment: What's the meaning of `iterate the same`? Do you want to get the content of blob and show in a csv file or any other format? Please show more details.

Comment: @JoeyCai No, i need to get the rows from csv which is present in blob container and convert into json through logic app in azure

Comment: Refer to the suggestions mentioned in this link.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0ea1adc-1979-44df-a4d1-52290338bc78/transform-csv-in-logic-app?forum=azurelogicapps

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT Unable to see any reference from above link

Answer (score 3):

You could combine the logic app with Azure Function to implement it.

1. Blob connector to get the file .
2. Pass CSV content to function and return JSON
3. Iterate the row values.

And about the Azure Function you could refer to this [blog](https://arkeytek.com/2018/03/03/azure-functions-csv-to-json), in this example it has a complete Logic flow to convert csv into Json.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

**Update:**
I test the function in this [blog](https://arkeytek.com/2018/03/03/azure-functions-csv-to-json), the source code is [here](https://github.com/aaronralls/FunctionAppCSVToJSON), blow is my test page:

[image]

And here is result page:

[image]

I copied the result to get the complete output:

```
{
  "fileName": "MyTestCSVFile.csv",
  "rows": [
    {
      "ID": "    1",
      "Name": "Aaron",
      "Score": "99"
    },
    {
      "ID": "    2",
      "Name": "Dave",
      "Score": "55"
    },
    {
      "ID": "    3",
      "Name": "Susy",
      "Score": "77 "
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any size limitation for csv file in azure blob?

Comment: @sudhanshu Pal , normally azure Function could complete the task, did you change the Function code to match your csv file? If this way could meet your requirements, you could try this, but it's really a little complex. https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/microsoft-flow-advanced-tutorial-creating-a-csv-converter-from-scratch/

Comment: Can you send me your csv file so i will test that with your function?

Comment: @sudhanshu Pal , I update my answer, you could check it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the Logic App? Functions have a blob trigger that can fire on new blobs.

Comment: @ evilSnobu it's sudhanshu Pal requirements, he mentioned he need logic app to iterate the json content, so I provided the proposal.

Comment: @sudhanshu Pal ,any more questions, if my answer is helpful, you could mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeChen how can i parse this value from function. This is an address "Tower C, 1st Floor, Y-Block,Phase-III". If field contain that kind of value then what will be the approach to write the function

Comment: @GeorgeChen How can i parse this line 1003,,Test,Test,"Location, US",,Virtual City,,US,Virtual Location-US,99999,,Software,"Pal, Sudhanshu",Sudhanshu,,,,Sudhanshu,INACTIVE,11/10/2015,12/3/2015

Comment: @GeorgeChen static Regex csvSplit = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static string[] SplitCSV(string input)
{

  List<string> list = new List<string>();
  string curr = null;
  foreach (Match match in csvSplit.Matches(input))
  {        
    curr = match.Value;
    if (0 == curr.Length)
    {
      list.Add("");
    }

    list.Add(curr.TrimStart(','));
  }

  return list.ToArray();
}

Comment: @GeorgeChen, can i use regex like this:   Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
                String[] Fields = CSVParser.Split(line);
                csv.Add(Fields);

Comment: Updated Link to the blog https://arkeytek.com/blog/learn-about-azure-functions-and-how-to-convert-csv-data-to-json?rq=CSV%20to%20JSON