# Is there a solution to split a flat file (txt) using Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, split, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to upload some flat files (FTP) to the Azure service bus using the Azure Logic application. since the size exceeds the ASB quota, I have to split the file, then send it.

i tried to modify the trigger's code by adding the 'SplitOn' function.

```
...
"splitOn":"@triggerbody()",
...
```

but in vain !

content body of the file :

```
Code Implant;Nbr;Num Group;
NF5;5;1;
NF5;2;3;
NF46;1;1;
NF46;2;2;
...
```

[My Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMx8E.jpg)

[Trigger's setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS0Hs.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you expereincing an error? Can you elaborate on your issue more?

Comment: One option is to use Azure Data Factory (ADF) to split the files that are coming into Azure.  There is no connector from ADF to service bus so you could use Logic Apps as the broker between ADF and SB.  This might be overkill for what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @technogeek1995, I add some captures.

Comment: The flat files don't support splitOn. You need to convert the flat file into xml or JSON before you do the debatching .

Comment: @KenWMSFT, it's too difficult to use ADF. too large for a simple workflow.

Comment: @GeorgeChen , can you please suggest me a solution?
i mean, how can i convert this content to Json :

Code Implant;Nbr;Num Group;
NF5;5;1;
NF5;2;3;
NF46;1;1;
NF46;2;2;
...

Comment: You could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2017/05/19/logic-app-flat-file-encoding-and-decoding-documentation-references/) and this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-flatfile).

Comment: thank you @GeorgeChen but it s not what im looking for !

Comment: About how to parse flat file to json, you could refer to my before [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232890/10383250). You could call Azure function use the Azure Function connector to get the json data then use spliton function.